# How to connect to current container when starting Docker?

Tags: mongodb, vagrant, virtualbox, docker

Basically, I'm trying to initialize a mongo database after spinning it up with Docker by using a mongodump and mongorestore.  The mongorestore fails because it can't connect to the hostname of the container.  Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried `localhost` instead and it doesn't work either.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo

RUN mongodump --host merchdev02.bcinfra.net --port 27017 --db ap
RUN mongorestore --host $(hostname) --port 27017 --db ap
```

The error:

```
A Docker command executed by Vagrant didn't complete successfully!
The command run along with the output from the command is shown
below.

Command: "docker" "build" "/mnt/docker_build_52c7cc3c5608022927f471820455e02b"

Stderr: Sending build context to Docker daemon 26.62 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
2014/09/12 12:32:46 The command [/bin/sh -c mongorestore --host $(hostname) --port 27017 --db ap] returned a non-zero code: 255

Stdout: Step 0 : FROM mongo
 ---> 37ee18fca8d2
Step 1 : RUN mongodump --host merchdev02.bcinfra.net --port 27017 --db ap
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 176612e279d2
Step 2 : RUN mongorestore --host $(hostname) --port 27017 --db ap
 ---> Running in 365bd8348ed1
2014-09-12T12:32:46.444+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 172.17.0.25:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
couldn't connect to [5d533df6cbc4:27017] couldn't connect to server 5d533df6cbc4:27017 (172.17.0.25), connection attempt failed
```

I'm using Vagrant to bootstrap Docker.  My Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end
  # Setup docker
  config.vm.define "mongo" do |v|
    v.vm.synced_folder "logs", "/var/log/mongodb"
    v.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
      d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "../host-vm/Vagrantfile"
      d.build_dir = "."
      d.ports = ['27017:27017']
      d.remains_running = true
      d.name = "mongo"
    end
  end
end
```

And finally my host VM for Docker containers to use:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.provision "docker"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline:
    "ps aux | grep 'sshd:' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 27017, host: 27017
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `mongorestore --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --db ap`?

Comment: @BenWhaley Yep.  No luck.

Comment: Are you sure Mongo is running at that point? I don't think it would be, it hasn't been started earlier in the Dockerfile

Comment: I guess mongodb is not running when building your image.

Comment: Pretty sure you guys are right.  I didn't realize the CMD didn't run until you actually run the image.  So I probably need to do the dump and restore in ONBUILD instructions and use that image as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo container sets mongod as its command `CMD["mongod"]` which means that it does not run until you actually do `docker run ...`

I normally always include a script `ADD init.sh` into my docker containers to handle any such configuration tasks that don't make sense at build time.

Comment: Does init.sh get executed automatically or do you have to add a CMD to run it on startup?

Comment: You have to add a CMD